# Am I using the correct data type in schema.org for a job site?

Tags: rich-snippets

I'm having a hard time chosing the best data type in `schema.org` for my local job site.

We're offering premium job postings for employers. Currently, I'm using the data type `local business` with Google Structured Data Markup Helper. Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

[Local business](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) is a correct type to use. And on each listing you would want to mark it up with the "intangible" [job posting](http://schema.org/JobPosting) type.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following schema.

http://schema.org/JobPosting

Also u could use attach the publisher markup. (link to a google+ page with rel=publisher)